# gxt, gwt, Java. Validation of textfield without infobubble

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, uibinder

I have to check some `textField` with the following rule:

```
if (the value A != the value B) {
  this.A.forceInvalid("");
}
```

This work really fine, but I want to remove the "info bubble" of the error,on the textfield.
I have tried to simply put a css with red border around it, but it seems that my superior dont want that.

How can I erase that bubble?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, this validation looks wrong. It seems you are using gxt `Field` which already has built-in validators. Here is an example:

```
yourField.addValidator(new Validator<String>() {

  @Override
  public List<EditorError> validate(Editor<String> editor, String value) {
    final List<EditorError> errors = new ArrayList<EditorError>();
    if (!value.equals("test")) {
      errors.add(new DefaultEditorError(yourField, "Value is not \"test\"", value));
    }
    return errors;
  }
});
```

By default it looks like this:
[image: buble validation]
You can change it by using non-default `ErrorHandler` on the field. It is not clear what exactly do you want, as far as I can understand you want to get rid of (!) sign and its popup. I think that `TitleErrorHandler` will suit your needs.

```
yourField.setErrorSupport(new TitleErrorHandler(yourField));
```

[image: simple error]